# xubuntu - is it better than xfce on ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I really like ubuntu. Have used slackware, fedora, and suse. I also love xfce. What I do requieres lots and lots of memory, and usually I have many things running, so a light desktop really helps.

But xfce keeps having issues. I mean, one week the upper panel disappears, and I learn how to solve that. The next week, it's something else. Now the desktop is gone, and everywhere I read people recommend a re-install...

Now, I installed ubuntu, and then added the xfce desktop. My question is:

Could my problems be related to installing both unity+gnome+xfce on the same machine? If I install xubuntu should it be more stable? has any one had real experience on this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a question that is more suited for ubuntuforums.org: it is more about experiences than about solving a problem. AU likes to fix things for you but then you will need to post those problems you have (separate questions preferred).

Answer (score 0):

I have had experience with it and I can't see where your problem is coming from. I currently have the equivalent of K/L/X/Ubuntu and Gnome Shell and more - and neither desktop usually majorly affects the other.

However, you did say that what you do requires a lot of memory, and this could be a part of the issue, as the system may be a little unstable (no matter the Desktop environment or what is installed) when it begins to run out of memory.

Another possibility is simply that you may be changing things and not noticing (I have known people to change panel items by accident for example) - or, your system may simply be encountering bugs.

To sum it all up, your problem is not from running XFCE and Unity on the same system.